# How to use bundler for a project that works in jruby and ruby

Tags: ruby, jruby, bundler

How do you use bundler with a project that works for both jruby and ruby?

Specifically, some gems are required in one but not the other, as well as different versions.

Reference: http://github.com/docwhat/iated

Comment: Groups are the best solution. But if you don't want to always specify them, you can add an **if RUBY_VERSION ~= /java/**, but it isn't really ideal.

Comment: It's actually pretty bad. You get different `Gemfile.lock` files for each platform so it's constantly being rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'gem_that_only_works_with_regular_ruby'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'gem_that_only_works_with_jruby'
end
```